# corda: Stateが"UNCONSUMED"から"CONSUMED"に変更される条件とは？

Tags: java

Cordaでアプリケーションを実装していますが、同じStateを複数入力しても、過去に入力したStateが"UNCONSUMED"になりません。
このステータスが変化するには、特定の実装が必要と推測しています。どうすればステータスが変更される実装が出来ますか？サンプルソースも付けて頂けると嬉しいです。

自己解決してしまいました

TransactionをCreateする際に、消費させたい（ヒストリカルにしたい）StateをTransactionのInputに指定して実行する。

Comment: 可能であれば実際のコード等を載せてもらった方が回答も付きやすいと思います。

Comment: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example をgit cloneして下さい。

Comment: @Shin 問題を再現する手順も含め、コメントではなく質問文に直接追記して頂ければと思います。コメントは後から質問を見に来た方からは読みにくいからです。また、質問を編集するとこの質問がより閲覧されやすくなります。質問文の下の「編集」から自由に行えますので、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @Shin お疲れ様でした :) 自己解決した場合でも、このサイトでは[自分で回答を投稿できます](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)。むしろそれを推奨しています。投稿後しばらくすると解決済みとして承認もできますので、是非お願いいたします。

Comment: 回答しました。宜しくお願いします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TransactionをCreateする際に、消費させたい（ヒストリカルにしたい）StateをTransactionのInputに指定して実行する。

```
        final TransactionBuilder txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary)
                .addOutputState(yourSate, YOUR_CONTRACT_ID)
                .addInputState(this.stateAndRef)
                .addCommand(txCommand);
```